# model with different friction

Tags: ros, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create an SDF object in gazebo that has different surface friction values at different points to
test how controller respond to the ground changing. Is it possible to do this using SDF?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404413/model-with-different-friction/) by [mercury](https://answers.ros.org/users/21287/mercury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-07-30**:
Have you done a search at https://answers.gazebosim.org ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried this, but I would look at creating multiple rectangular `models`, each having different `friction` properties, then position instances of these models so they form a continuous surface. If you make the z-dimension very short, you could even place them on top of a standard ground plane (so there's no edge-of-world for your robot to fall off of.)

Follow-up thought: I assume you are aware that gazebo's ODE friction calculations are very crude. Don't be surprised if your simulation results seem quite unrealistic.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mercury](https://answers.ros.org/users/21287/mercury/) on 2022-08-01**:
that is a very good idea, thank you!